# OpenThread Border Router setup on RPi Zero W

Tags: openthread

I am currently building a cost efficient Open Thread network. In my setup i have few Full thread devices and Minimal Thread Device which will be sending data to cloud via Border Router. I have currently setup a RCP design Open Thread Border Router on RPi 3B+ by following the open thread docs and its working fine.

Doc Link: [Open Thread Border Router Build and Configuration](https://openthread.io/guides/border-router/build)

Now as i want my final product to be as cost efficient as it can be, i would like to consider using RPi Zero W for setting up my Open Thread Border Router. So i was following the same steps mentioned in OTBR doc to setup it on RPi Zero W, i came across this line in Step 3 which states " Before you continue, **make sure your configured hardware platform is connected to the internet using Ethernet**. The bootstrap script disables the platform's WiFi interface and the setup script requires internet connectivity to download and install several packages. "

But my RPi Zero W only have WiFi interface. So i wanted to know, is it even possible to run OTBR setup on RPi Zero W ?

I have also read in docs that "Open Thread Border Router (OTBR) provides **support for the Raspberry Pi 3B or newer** (RPi) platform". But have anyone tried the same setup on RPi Zero W and was successful ?  Because in the end as i said, i would like my final product to be as cost effective as possible.

Also find the attachment of the error i am facing:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are not setting `NETWORK_MANAGER=1` when running `./script/setup`, I think it would work with just the Wi-Fi interface.

You can try running the following setup command:

```
INFRA_IF_NAME=wlan0 ./script/setup
```

Comment: Hello, but my issue arise in the 2nd step itself, i have attached the image in the post now. The command you mentioned is 3rd step, which is to be run if 2nd step runs properly.

Comment: See my response to your duplicate inquiries: https://groups.google.com/g/openthread-users/c/bC7tnIfmO1w/m/xEAJZYjVAAAJ